# Trying not to bypass JavaScript framework for a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am going through an already written code by someone for a webapp and making some changes in it. It's kind of a framework which is used but since my question is only concerned with a particular functioning of the system, I am trying my best to provide as much relevant details I can. I have also tried to create a slightly functional JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akhare/L5jarh3p/) to provide the basic context.

As can be seen in the JavaScript section of JS Fiddle, the `initialize` function defined at Line #19 is basically defining menubar, menubarlink and footer.

In the HTML section of JSFiddle, line #23, I see the following defined:

```
<li><a href="#userAdministration" onclick="location.href='fragments/user_list_testpage.html'">User Administration</a></li>
```

The onclick section was added by me where I was using `location.href` to define the exact location of the HTML page.

**Problem I am facing:**

If I go with the above approach, when a user clicks on Admin option which brings down `User Administration` and `Reports` option. Upon clicking `User Administration` it is directly taking me to the `user_list_testpage.html` page which is obvious as per the above onclick definition. But by doing this, I am basically bypassing the menubar, menubarlink and footer section of the webpage. It just shows a web page without any menubar,menubarlink and footer section as mentioned in the `initialize` JavaScript function.

I was planning on doing something like this as mentioned in the commented code section of JavaScript starting at Line #13 but it just seems to me same as writing onclick above.

```
document.getElementById("userAdministration").onclick = function(){

            location.href = "/fragments/user_list_page.html";
        };
```

I am wondering how can I make sure that when a user clicks on `User Administration`, it has proper menubar,menubarlink and footer section? Do I need to include something in the `initialize` function? Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing the `href` attribute with the `id` attribute?

Comment: @Alon Eitan Could you please elaborate in the context of my code?Did you mean I should be including something in the `initialize` function?

Comment: In you fiddle, I searched (Ctrl+F) for `userAdministration` and saw a link with `href="#userAdministration"` but no element with `id="userAdministration"`

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah, that is how the current code exists. Could you tell me what changes I should probably be making in order to avoid bypassing the menubar stuff defined inside the initialize function?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can catch the event like this: `$(document).on('click', 'a[href="#userAdministration"]', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('You have clicked on the "#userAdministration" link'); });` (But remove the `onclick=....` from the element

Comment: @AlonEitan So, after removing the onclick, I should be defining the event catching code inside the `initialize` function or outside?

Comment: Outside, right after you call the `initialize` function

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks. That is basically catching the event when I click on User Administration option and displaying the alert. I am wondering if I want to take user to a HTML page after catching that event, what should be my approach considering that CSS is already defined, the `initialize` function is already doing the job of initializing the menubar, footer etc?

Comment: Then you can get the html by using ajax and append it to the container: `$.get( "/fragments/user_list_page.html, function( data ) { $( "#pageContainer" ).html( data ); });` ? (Am I right that this is what you're trying to do, or have I misunderstood what you need?)

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah, you are trying to provide the right information based on the information I have provided. I tried putting the `$.get` code inside the above event catching code as shown below ` $(document).on('click', 'a[href="#userAdministration"]', function(e) 
        {   e.preventDefault(); 
            //alert('You have clicked on the "#userAdministration" link'); 

            $.get("/fragments/user_list_page.html", function( data ) {

             $( "#pageContainer" ).html( data ); 

        });



        }); `  but for some reason it's not appending HTML. Nothing happens

Comment: Open the developer tools and check the **Network** tab - See if any request is being executed after you click on the link. It can also be due to an 404 error (Maybe the url should be `"fragments/user_list_page.html"`  instead of `"/fragments/user_list_page.html"`

Comment: @AlonEitan Great. It was 404 error. I had to use `fragments/user_list_page.html` eventually to make it work. Thanks very much.